Recursive for-loop conditions not working as expected
I'm new to java, and I'm working on a program to print Pascal's Triangle. The first row is row 0, and the first value in a row is in column 0. I have a for-loop, and I want to make it so that, at the end of a for loop, if the column is less than the row, the column is increased by one, otherwise the column is set to one and the row is increased by one. However, this is not happening.
This is my function and for loop:
// rowLimit = 10 in this example
static void printPascal (int row, int column, int rowLimit) {
    for (; row < rowLimit; row = (column < row) ? row : row + 1, column = (column < row) ? column + 1 : 1) {

Right now, I am just trying to get it to print the coordinates in order with the format (row, column). The output I expected was:
(0, 0)
1, 0)
1, 1)
2, 0)
2, 1)
2, 2) etc. all the way up to (9, 9)

However, the output I am getting is:
(0, 0)
1, 1)
2, 2)
3, 3)
4, 4)
5, 5)
6, 6) (7, 7)
8, 8)
9, 9)

I don't understand why both row and column are always just being incremented by 1.
(Full code if necessary):
package beginnerjava;

public class Test {
    static int getValue(int row, int column) {
        if (row <= 1 || column == 0 || column < row) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return getValue(row - 1, column) + getValue(row - 1, column - 1);
        }
    }

    static void printPascal (int row, int column, int rowLimit) {
        for (; row < rowLimit; row = (column < row) ? row : row + 1, column = (column < row) ? column + 1 : 1) {
                if (column < row) {
                    System.out.print("" + row + ", " + column + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("" + row + ", " + column + " ");
                }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPascal(0, 0, 10);
    }
    
}


The only recursion is in the getValue function. Which you never call. Loops are not recursive.

As for the problems you might have with the loop, I suggest you try to simplify everything in it as much as possible. Use functions calls if you need to. Then use a debugger to step through the code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what happens.

Also, where are the parentheses in the show output coming from? The code you show doesn't print any. Is it really a [mre]?

Lastly, simple and easy to read code is always better than complex and hard to understand code, especially for a beginner. Don't try to be "clever", it will almost never work out in the long run. Use multiple nested loops if you need to.

moved from Staging Ground: "1) not really recursive; 2) don't try to write all logic in one single line (misusing for statement) - hard to read, understand, maintain --- I would recommend two plain for loops."

Everything your code does, is done in the for declaration, this does not make it easy to read, and makes it easy to make mistakes, like the ones you have already been commented...
A Pascal pyramid is built starting from the top, assigning it a “1”, and in the lower rows, the value is the sum of the two boxes that are above (if there is more than one), something like:
   1
  1 1
 1 2 1
1 3 3 1

where the “2” is obtained from the sum of the two values of the previous row, the first “3” from the sum of “1” and “2” and the second from the sum of “2” and “1”.

int matrix[][];

int[][] generateTriangle( int rows ) {
     // create de matrix
   matrix = new int[ rows ][];     
   for( int row = 0; row < rows; row ++ ) {
        // we instantiate the array with the corresponding size
      matrix[ row ] = new int[ row + 1 ];
      for( int col = 0; col <= row; col ++ ) {
           // the first two rows are assigned “1”. 
           // to the following ones we assign the heat returned by **getNewValue**
         if( row < 2 )  matrix[ row ][ col ] = 1;
         else matrix[ row ][ col ] = getNewValue( row, col );
      }
   }
   return matrix;
}

int getNewValue( int row, int col ) {
     // in these cases we return "1" 
   if( col == 0 || col == row ) {
      return 1;
   }
     // we return the sum of the two items that are above it
   return matrix[ row - 1 ][ col - 1 ] + matrix[ row - 1 ][ col ];
}

void show( int matrix[][] ) {
   for( int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i ++ ) {
      System.out.println( "" );
      for( int k = 0; k < matrix[ i ].length; k ++ ) {
         System.out.print( matrix[ i ][ k ] + " " );
      }    
   }
}

public void exec(   ) {
   show( generateTriangle( 5 ) );
}



The (IMO) simplest way using two for loops:
static void printPascal (int rowLimit) {
    for (int row = 0; row < rowLimit; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
            System.out.printf("(%d,%d) ", row, col);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

Output for printPascal(4):

(0,0)
(1,0) (1,1)
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)
(3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3)



Thank you, this is genius compared to what i was doing! The printf thing is super cool too once i figured out what it was.

What's wrong in your code:

Incorrect reset Condition: The condition (column<row) does not ensure proper reset logic for column.

You can update your logic so that you can get expected output.
static void printPascal(int row, int column, int rowLimit) {
    for (; row < rowLimit; ) {
        System.out.println("(" + row + ", " + column + ")");
        if (column < row) {
            column++; // Move to the next column in the current row
        } else {
            column = 0; // Reset column for the next row
            row++;      // Move to the next row
        }
    }
}

